# Firebase Admin SDK Security for Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I use Google Cloud Functions in my Flutter app with the Admin SDK. Therefore, I initialised the SDK without parameters like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
```

I am wondering if I need to consider anything else for the setup to be secure. My understanding is that because the SDK is deployed in a Google environment, I don't need to create any security keys.

Is this correct, or could someone still access the database with the current setup?

I am sorry, my knowledge here is very basic. I am also not sure if the information I gave is sufficient for you to answer the question. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to consider.

Edit:
I followed this article: fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide (s. bottom of page - Step 2: Send Messages with NodeJS (Backend) )

Comment: It's not clear what your concern is.  Backend code running in Cloud Functions executes entirely in Google's cloud and not on any devices that might be calling it.  The code is only as secure as how you write it.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your quick response and apologies for not being clear. My concern is that when I added the SDK to my flutter app, I made it publicly available/visible. I followed this article: https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/ (s. bottom of page - Step 2: Send Messages with NodeJS (Backend) ). Do I need to consider any additional security features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the code that sends notifications is entirely on the backend, which is entirely under your control, there's nothing you need to do in your app other than ensure that the frontend is sending the correct data.

Comment: Thank you again Doug! I know this might have been a basic question, but I wanted to make sure there is nothing that I am missing.